# How to get machine-learning contributors from stackoverflow to join our site

Tags: discussion

I thought that machine learning is a niche on stackoverflow until I have checked just for fun the [corresponding tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning). It is true that some questions are more programming related than others, but I cannot get rid of the feeling that there are a lot of experts-by-practice with a solid background to answer more "theoretical" questions.

Since then I have already flagged two questions to make the SO-mods move them to our site in the hope of attracting more users from there:

- [using-a-histogram-to-estimate-class-label-densities-in-a-tree-learner](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19915/using-a-histogram-to-estimate-class-label-densities-in-a-tree-learner)
- [data-mining-classification-competition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19996/data-mining-classification-competition)

But I wonder a) if this is a valid strategy and b) what else we can do to attract more machine learners.

**Edit:** Redirection to metaoptimize. What a heresy !([see for yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238687/relational-fisher-kernel-implementation)).